# Spring neo4j cannot add relationships

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am looking at http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/ which runs fine when using an embedded database.

When running against a neo4j server the entities are saved but when trying to add the relationship and saving I'm getting an exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.getOrCreateRelationship(Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Node;Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Node;Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/RelationshipType;Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Direction;Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship;
```

I have no idea why this is being thrown. In addition it appears that this exception is caught and therefore I am unable to roll back the transaction so I can see the entities in the database after the program has run.

The line which causes the error:

```
personRepository.save(greg); // <-- This saves fine
greg.worksWith(roy); // Add relationship
greg.worksWith(craig); // Add relationship
personRepository.save(greg); // <-- This causes Spring exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDN 3 has never been built with remote databases in mind.

Full support for remote databases is delivered by SDN4, the first milestone is available. Read through http://neo4j.com/blog/graphconnect-europe-spring-data-neo4j/ and the linked pages there.

Comment: Have you used this? I'm having trouble converting the code. Getting org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [hello.Application$ApplicationConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7db8f792]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: hello.Application$ApplicationConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7db8f792.<init>()

Comment: There's a little jiggling around involved but I finally got it working. Thanks for the heads up on the new version.